# getting schema and data OUT OF SQL Server Compact into SQL Server LocalDB or SQL Anywhere (Sybase/SAP)

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, powerbuilder

I want to export the entire schema and daily data from a SQL Server Compact database (3.x) into a SQL Server LocalDB or Express database.  Evem better yet would be to pipe it daily into a Sybase/SAP SQL Anywhere database.

I would like to grab the Compact schema and port it to the other database, then set up a daily pipe to copy the data completely into the second database.

Any experts out there who know how to do this?  Are there data migration tools in SQL Server LocalDB / Express that can be automated to do this?

Even better yet, would be to have the database painter in Powerbuilder 12.5 (SAP/Sybase) be able to access the SQL Compact database....but I'm not going to hold my breath.  Powerbuilder could then do the data pipe.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my SQL Server Compact Tools on Codeplex to do this, either from GUI, coomad line or via a .NET API